# Packages/solutions to add online document editing to an on-premise web application

Tags: pdf, ms-office, ckeditor, google-docs, rich-internet-application

I'm doing research to find 3rd party packages/solutions/widgets/back-ends to allow users of a website to upload and edit office documents online in their browser, akin to Google Docs.  I haven't had much luck so wanted to see if anyone has any advice or pointers.

Integrating Google Docs is, sadly, not an option, as the documents have to remain stored on our servers only.

ckEditor (and similar) are good rich text content editors, but don't support page formatting and many other features of office documents.

I've found many libraries for converting MS Office, PDF, PS, etc. documents into a common format, but no editor widgets or front-ends that support editing that common format.

Advice on 3rd party solutions or other libraries/widgets I've missed would be really appreciated, whether OSS or proprietary.

Comment: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about office productivity suites? I've personally used [Zoho](http://www.zoho.com/) and thought it was okay. I'm not sure which of these offer document -> online editing -> save offline document, though.

Wikipedia has lists of these online productivity suites :

- [Online word processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Word_Processor#Online_Word_Processors)
- [Online Office Suites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_office_suite)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a [Volume Licensed](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/) customer of MSFT, you can deploy [Office Web Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee815687.aspx) (2010) on-premise with SharePoint 2010. TechNet subscribers can also [get it](http://technet.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx?pv=1:407) - this is what I did - for testing. Everything is x64 (Web Apps, SharePoint, etc.)